# converting json format to work with d3

Tags: arrays, json, d3.js

I am having problems formatting json to suit my needs for d3.
This is the incoming json.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "terms": "https://currencylayer.com/terms",
  "privacy": "https://currencylayer.com/privacy",
  "timeframe": true,
  "start_date": "2010-03-01",
  "end_date": "2010-03-04",
  "source": "USD",
  "quotes": {
    "2010-03-01": {   
        "USDCAD": 1.31
    },
    "2010-03-02": {    
        "USDCAD": 1.32
    },
      "2010-03-03": {   
      "USDCAD": 1.34
    }
  }
}
```

i need to format it somehow to resemble the array below.

```
[
 {"date":"2010-03-01","USDCAD": 1.31},
 {"date":"2010-03-02","USDCAD": 1.32},  
 {"date":"2010-03-03","USDCAD": 1.33}, 
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, post the relevant code with your effort and you will likely get more help here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: tried a few things that resulted in errors, clueless here :(

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up with, not sure if it is the most efficient but it works.

```
d3.json(./somedata.json, function (response) {          

var newdata = response.quotes;                        
data = []

for (var i in newdata) {                          
var datacopy = newdata[i];
datacopy.date = i;
data.push(datacopy)
}
```